# How to user input an infinity value to a QDoubleSpinBox?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5

I'm trying to set up a QDoubleSpinBox in Python 3.7 with PyQt5, that can take a range of values from -np.inf to np.inf. I would also like the user to set the values to either of those, -np.inf or np.inf. How would I/the user do that?

After adjusting the minimum and maximum of the QDoubleSpinBox it is possible to set the value in code and either "-inf" or "inf" shows up in the displayed box.

```py
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QDoubleSpinBox

[...]

dsbTest = QDoubleSpinBox()

# first set the desired range 
dsbTest.setRange(-np.inf, np.inf)

# set the value to positive infinity, successfully
dsbTest.setValue(np.inf)
```

However, after changing it to any other value, let's say 5, I find myself unable to enter "-inf" or "inf" back into the GUI.

When I type "i" or "inf", no input is taken, by which I mean, the displayed current value does not change from 5.

Comment: You do understand that while you can state this you cannot actually implement this without some complex processing since you do have limits to the size that a number can be.  Further it is rather unrealistic since no one really needs to go anywhere near infinity when inputting a number just make them very very big and you should be just fine.

Comment: As for trying to enter text into a numeric field you would have to grab the keypress event and if "i" then via code input the "inf" or "-inf" value.

Comment: Spinning doubles is not as interesting as spinning ordered and discrete sets. In this case, could not you live with just a QLineEdit with a validator ?

Comment: @DennisJensen as I did not know yet how big a very very big number would have to be, I decided to work with np.inf, which has been working fine so far.

Comment: @DennisJensen I will try catching "i" input, thank you!

Comment: @LaurentG I found the spinning very convenient for the user and the widget has a validator already in it.

Comment: A workaround could be, to provide two extra buttons to set `-np.inf` and `np.inf`. With the resp. Unicode point (`U+221E`), you even could give them nice labels like `-∞` and `+∞`... ;-)

Comment: I like @Scheff idea as it seems to be the simplest and easiest to implement and very clear to the user what they are doing.

Comment: If there is room enough, I think it is a good choice too.

Comment: @Scheff solved it by overwriting keyPressEvent and catching "Home" and "End" buttons to assign min and max value. I thought that would be intuitive, as arrow keys and page up and page down can be used to incrementally change the value. However I will show a tool tip for help. Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I ended up doing it like this, making a subclass.

```
class InftyDoubleSpinBox(QDoubleSpinBox):

    def __init__(self):
        super(QDoubleSpinBox, self).__init__()

        self.setMinimum(-np.inf)
        self.setMaximum(np.inf)

    def keyPressEvent(self, e: QtGui.QKeyEvent):

        if e.key() == QtCore.Qt.Key_Home:
            self.setValue(self.maximum())
        elif e.key() == QtCore.Qt.Key_End:
            self.setValue(self.minimum())
        else:
            super(QDoubleSpinBox, self).keyPressEvent(e)
```

I set minimum and maximum at the beginning to -np.inf, np.inf. In the keyPressEvent Home and End Buttons will be caught, to set the value to minimum or maximum.

For any other key, the QDoubleSpinBox will react as usual, as the base function is called.

This also works for other assigned min/max values after **init**() is called. Which was desirable for my case.

Answer (score 0):

`float("inf")` or `float("INF")` or `float("Inf")` or `float("inF")` or `float("infinity")` creates a `float` object holding **infinity**

`float("-inf")` or `float("-INF")` or `float("-Inf")` or `float("-infinity")` creates a float object holding **negative infinity**

We can set `-infinity` as the **minimum value** and `+infinity` as **maximum value** to a `QDoubleSpinBox`

```
box = QDoubleSpinBox()
box.setMinimum(float("-inf"))
box.setMaximum(float("inf"))
```

### Source:

```
import sys

from PySide6.QtWidgets import QMainWindow, QApplication, QDoubleSpinBox, QWidget, QFormLayout, QLineEdit, QPushButton


def getDoubleSpinBox() -> QDoubleSpinBox:
    box = QDoubleSpinBox()
    box.setPrefix("₹")
    box.setMinimum(float("-inf"))
    box.setMaximum(float("inf"))
    box.setSingleStep(0.05)
    box.setValue(25_000)
    return box


def getLineEdit(placehoder: str, password: bool = False):
    lineEdit = QLineEdit()
    lineEdit.setPlaceholderText(placehoder)
    if password:
        lineEdit.setEchoMode(QLineEdit.Password)
    return lineEdit


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.setWindowTitle("Open Bank")
        self.widget = QWidget()
        self.widgetLayout = QFormLayout()
        self.widgetLayout.addRow("ID", getLineEdit(placehoder="Investor name"))
        self.widgetLayout.addRow("Investment", getDoubleSpinBox())
        self.widgetLayout.addRow("Password", getLineEdit(placehoder="Enter secret password", password=True))
        self.widgetLayout.addRow(QPushButton("Invest"), QPushButton("Cancel"))
        self.widget.setLayout(self.widgetLayout)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.widget)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    win = MainWindow()
    win.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

### Window:

[image: Open Bank]